# Animate SVG electron around ring

Tags: jquery, css, animation, graphics, svg

I have the following `.svg` graphic:

[image]

I am trying to animate the electron so that it moves (proportionally with the page when it is scrolled) along the curvature of the ring up until a certain point (probably the same point the electron would be at if it was flipped over the imaginary x-axis of this image):

[image]

I am fairly new to web-development, so I am unsure how I would accomplish this.  I imagine that I would have to use CSS3 for the actual animation, and jQuery to capture the scroll event; yet I really don't have a clue as to where I would start.

The optimized `.svg` code for reference:

```
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="436.25" height="456.5" version="1.1">
    <style>
        .s0 {
            fill:#1c1f26;
        }
    </style>
    <g transform="translate(-225.94052,-31.584209)">
        <path d="m259.84 71.78c-120.47 0-218.12 102.2-218.12 228.25 0 126.05 97.65 228.25 218.13 228.25 120.47 0 218.13-102.2 218.13-228.25 0-126.05-97.65-228.25-218.12-228.25zm0 4.78c117.95 0 213.56 100.05 213.56 223.47C473.41 423.45 377.8 523.5 259.84 523.5 141.89 523.5 46.25 423.45 46.25 300.03 46.25 176.61 141.89 76.56 259.84 76.56z" transform="translate(184.22177,-40.197041)" fill="#1c1f26" />
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(-81.915798,-31.584205)">
        <g transform="matrix(-0.25881905,-0.96592583,0.96592583,-0.25881905,129.87282,611.33082)" fill="#1c1f26">
            <path transform="matrix(1.0061861,-0.5809218,0.5809218,1.0061861,-135.78147,130.45415)" d="m279.91 300.03c0 11.09-8.99 20.07-20.07 20.07-11.09 0-20.07-8.99-20.07-20.07 0-11.09 8.99-20.07 20.07-20.07 11.09 0 20.07 8.99 20.07 20.07zM279.91 300.03 279.91 300.03" fill="#1c1f26" />
            <path d="m279.91 300.03c0 11.09-8.99 20.07-20.07 20.07-11.09 0-20.07-8.99-20.07-20.07 0-11.09 8.99-20.07 20.07-20.07 11.09 0 20.07 8.99 20.07 20.07z" transform="matrix(1.0061861,-0.5809218,0.5809218,1.0061861,-110.83616,87.416816)" fill="#1c1f26" />
            <path transform="matrix(1.0061861,-0.5809218,0.5809218,1.0061861,-160.5781,87.330591)" d="m279.91 300.03c0 11.09-8.99 20.07-20.07 20.07-11.09 0-20.07-8.99-20.07-20.07 0-11.09 8.99-20.07 20.07-20.07 11.09 0 20.07 8.99 20.07 20.07z" fill="#1c1f26" />
        </g>
        <path class="electron" d="m107.76 150.64c0 6.53-5.3 11.83-11.83 11.83-6.53 0-11.83-5.3-11.83-11.83 0-6.53 5.3-11.83 11.83-11.83 6.53 0 11.83 5.3 11.83 11.83z" transform="translate(120.35903,-99.340798)" fill="#1c1f26" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

I labeled the electron in the code with the `class="electron"`.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, i can help you, but i don't get the movement roll. correct me if i'm wrong! you want to change the electron position between two point (flipped over the imaginary x-axis of this image) by each mouse wheel up or down?

Comment: @MeTe-30 Not quite 180˚, you're flipping over the line roughly equal to `y = x`.  Flip the electron over the x-axis going through the middle of the image.

Comment: that was my mistake, i correct that.

Comment: Is that only me or is that circle not really a circle? It's an egg!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your SVG code can be optimised a bit more, since it consists entirely of circle primitives:

```xhtml
<svg width="80" height="80" style="position:fixed; top:5px; left:5px;">
  <g transform="translate(40,40)">
    <g id="a1" transform="rotate(40)">
      <circle cx="0" cy="5" r="4" fill="#1c1f26" />
      <circle cx="4.33" cy="-2.5" r="4" fill="#1c1f26" />
      <circle cx="-4.33" cy="-2.5" r="4" fill="#1c1f26" />
    </g>
    <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="37" fill="none" stroke="#1c1f26" stroke-width="1" />
    <g id="a2" transform="rotate(160)">
      <circle cx="0" cy="37" r="3" fill="#1c1f26" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

The rotation of the electron can easily be achieved by hooking into the `window.onscroll` event:

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
  var s = ($(window).scrollTop() / ($(document).height() - $(window).height()));
  var r1 = 40+106*s, r2=160-320*s;
  $("#a1").attr("transform","rotate("+r1+")");
  $("#a2").attr("transform","rotate("+r2+")");
});
```

This example rotates the nucleus of the atom too; you can delete this if not required.

[**You can see it working here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/LAe3g/2/)

---

### How it works:

The `<svg>` element is sized at 80×80 pixels, and the top-level `<g>` element shifts the origin of the drawing coordinates by 40 pixels horizontally and vertically to the middle of the image. So when we change the rotation of the two `<g>` elements inside it, we can be sure that they will rotate around the centre of the image.

The electron is just a plain circle offset vertically by 37 pixels in the +y direction (which happens to be towards the *bottom* of the screen), and the `g#a2` element gives it an initial (clockwise) rotation of 160° so it appears just left of the top of the orbital.

In the window's scroll handler event, `s` is set to the current scroll position as a value ranging from 0 (top) to 1 (bottom), and this value is used to change the rotation angle of the electron over the range from +160° to –160° (or +160° to +20° in the modified version discussed in the comments.

Comment: Almost perfect!  The one thing that I can't figure out how to fix is how to stop the electron at that exact point every time, even if there is more text in the document.  I've added another picture to show where I would like the animation to stop, once that's been figured out I will accept this answer

Comment: Oh, sorry. I saw `x axis` and read it as `y axis`. Just change `r2=160-320*s;` to `r2=160-140*s;` in the scroll handler. (That way the angle varies between 160° and 20°). [Updated JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/LAe3g/3/)

Comment: Could you go a bit more in-depth with the math involved in your answer?  I'm still trying to figure out how it all works.

Comment: @syb0rg I've added a bit of explanation to my answer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Does this links help you?

1. [[ Sample 1 ]](http://jsfiddle.net/rmj99/10/)
2. [[ Sample 2 ]](http://jsfiddle.net/aparnet/FzU39/5/light/)

below code is for scroll detecting:

```
if (document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener("mousewheel", onDocumentMouseWheel, false);
    document.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", onDocumentMouseWheel, false);
}
else {
    document.attachEvent("onmousewheel", onDocumentMouseWheel);
}

function onDocumentMouseWheel(e) {

    if ((e.type == 'mousewheel' && e.wheelDelta > 0) || (e.type == 'DOMMouseScroll' && e.detail < 0)) {
        //UP      
    }
    else {
        //DOWN
    }

}
```

and for animating svg, you have 2 option! CSS3, and SVG inline animation!
in CSS3 you have to use `transform` properties, like `translateX`, `translateY` and ...
in `[ Sample 1 ]` i show you, how to animate with CSS3, and for better performance, i used [`VELOCITY.JS`](https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity) instead of JQuery. (forgive me because of low accuracy on rotating!, i just wanted to show you that it's possible)
in `[ Sample 2 ]` i show you, how to animate with pure svg properties, that called SVG inline animation.

Comment: But it doesn't respond to window scrolling, just mouse wheel motion. Scrolling using the keyboard or scrollbar will have no effect.